# Is it possible for a Snowpark stored procedure to produce a DataFrame as its output?

Tags: python, dataframe, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create an snowflake stored procedure using snowpark. Inside of the procedure I will create some dataframe and performs some operations like filter, sort, join etc. At the end I just want to return that "dataframe", does snowpark supports that? Can someone provide an example of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supported - [Writing Snowpark Code in Python Worksheets](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/python-worksheets)

1. Python Worksheet

[image]

2. Run + Deploy

[image]

3. Code is wrapped as Stored Procedure and ready to be used

[image]

4. Call in SQL

   ```
   CALL ProcName();
   ```

[image]

5. Call in Python

[image]

Comment: Good examples! Thank you. In general you can use `return Table()` but `RETURNS TABLE(col col_type, ...)` to define the return type is prefered if you know the column outputs for the table as some dataframe operations might raise issues as the output schema cannot be inferred if column types are not defined.